# Determining which entries in input vector have the greatest effect on output vector

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for a solution in Python. I'm doing a project where I've built a densely packed neural network which takes a 48-dimensional input vector and the last layer is a 2-dimensional linear output. I'm looking for an algorithm that can determine how much each scalar in the input vector contributes to the output vector.

Specifically, my input vector is 24 consecutive pairs of position and momentum. For example the input would be $(x_1,v_1,x_2,v_2,...,x_{24},v_{24})$ and my output is the next position and momentum pair $(x_{25},v_{25})$. I've hypothesized that the more recent (higher index) pair should impact the output more. Is there any technique that I could use to quantitatively verify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to understand how many of the previous pairs affect the next pair ($x_{25}, v_{25}$). Given that you are tlaking about physical properties (position and momentum), I think it will always be the case that the most recent timesteps are most relevant, but you can verify this statistically.

#### Terminology:

You have a time-series dataset, with 24 "lags" and want to predict ahead with a horizon of 1. This equates to an *edogenous auto-regressive model* - a model that uses past values of itself to predict the future. (exogenous models could in your model include other variables, such as air humidity, viscosity surrounding medium, wind etc.)

### [**Partial Autocorrelation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_autocorrelation_function)

Given this context, you can try running a Partial Autocorrelation Function on your data. It will tell you how well correlated each points it, pair-wise, with each of the preceding 24 lags. Doing so in Python, using the [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf.html) package will give you a nice plot like this:

[image: PACF output]

Each vertical line tells you how correlated that particular lag is with the next value in the series ($x_{25}, v_{25}$).

Have a look at [**this thread on Cross Validated**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134487/analyse-acf-and-pacf-plots) for more detail and some code snippets.

---

### **Models**

There are other iterative model fitting techniques that can give you a final model, which can be interpreted and allow you to see which input variables (i.e. which of your 24 past data points were most important in fitting the model). you can have a look at component-wise gradient boosting. [Here is a tutorial with some theory and examples.](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/12754/1/tr120.pdf). It is only available in R as far as I know, but it isn't very difficult to get working, using the example code in that tutorial.
It essentially only updates the coefficient (seen as "importance") of a single lags at a time. So after fully training the model, each coefficient's magnitude encodes it's relevance in predicting the next value - that is exactly what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in the interpretation of neural networks but I have two suggestions. 
1: Alter the values of the input, one feature at a time, and watch how the output varies.
2: Use another model with more interpretability. You could do this just for interpretation.